# cubic spline interpolation in R

Tags: r, plot, spline, cubic

I am trying an implementation of a cubic spline in R. I have already used the spline, smooth.spline and smooth.Pspline functions that are available in the R libraries but I am not that happy with the results so I want to convince myself about the consistency of the results by a "homemade" spline function. I have already computed the coefficients for the 3rd degree polynomials, but I am not sure how to plot the results..they seem random points. You can find the source code below. Any help would be appreciated.

```
x = c(35,36,39,42,45,48)
y = c(2.87671519825595, 4.04868309245341,   3.95202175000174,   
  3.87683188946186, 4.07739945984612,   2.16064840967985)


n = length(x)

#determine width of intervals
h=0
for (i in 1:(n-1)){
   h[i] = (x[i+1] - x[i])
}

A = 0
B = 0
C = 0
D = 0
#determine the matrix influence coefficients for the natural spline
for (i in 2:(n-1)){
  j = i-1
  D[j] = 2*(h[i-1] + h[i])
  A[j] = h[i]
  B[j] = h[i-1] 

}

#determine the constant matrix C
for (i in 2:(n-1)){
  j = i-1
  C[j] = 6*((y[i+1] - y[i]) / h[i] - (y[i] - y[i-1]) / h[i-1])
}

#maximum TDMA length
ntdma = n - 2

#tridiagonal matrix algorithm

#upper triangularization
R = 0
for (i in 2:ntdma){
  R = B[i]/D[i-1]
  D[i] = D[i] - R * A[i-1]
  C[i] = C[i] - R * C[i-1] 
}

#set the last C
C[ntdma] = C[ntdma] / D[ntdma]

#back substitute
for (i in (ntdma-1):1){
  C[i] = (C[i] - A[i] * C[i+1]) / D[i]
}

#end of tdma

#switch from C to S
S = 0
for (i in 2:(n-1)){
  j = i - 1
  S[i] = C[j]
}
#end conditions
S[1] <- 0 -> S[n]

#Calculate cubic ai,bi,ci and di from S and h
for (i in 1:(n-1)){
 A[i] = (S[i+ 1] - S[i]) / (6 * h[i])
 B[i] = S[i] / 2
 C[i] = (y[i+1] - y[i]) / h[i] - (2 * h[i] * S[i] + h[i] * S[i + 1]) / 6
 D[i] = y[i]
}


#control points
xx = c(x[2],x[4])
yy = 0
#spline evaluation
for (j in 1:length(xx)){
  for (i in 1:n){
    if (xx[j]<=x[i]){
      break
    }
    yy[i] = A[i]*(xx[j] - x[i])^3 + B[i]*(xx[j] - x[i])^2 + C[i]*(xx[j] - x[i]) + D[i]

 }
points(x,yy ,col="blue")
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure that this should be tagged R?  This code doesn't make use of any of the R paradigms, e.g. vectorisation or applying functions.  Rewrite this in R paradigm and I'll have a look.

Comment: It should be tagged with R and that is the main idea: I do not want to make use of any built-in R functions. The main problem is at the plotting. I want to create this spline function to apply it on non equidistant time steps as I am not sure about the underlaying mechanism of the spline functions in R. Later on I can convert it to a more R specific coding.

Comment: Cut n paste fail: Error in h[i] = (x[i + 1] - x[i]) : object 'h' not found. Also, yy is uninitialised.

Comment: You don't have to make use of any higher level R functions to take advantage of vectorization.  Your code looks very much like C, not R.  I strongly suggest you take the time to learn how to 'think' in R, for which there are any number of excellent guides.  P.S. When my results do not align with those of a published package, I generally first question my own results not the package's.  To do otherwise is to have a G-d complex, which perhaps explains your choice of username.

Comment: @Spacedman ok .. added the initializations.. no more cut n paste "fail" depends on what interpreter you have.. for me I am able to run it. Sorry anyways

Comment: gsk23 my question was simple enough and I told you that I wanted to have a comparison between the results of the built-in functions of R and a "homemade" function as I did not find any specification of the algorithm that is used. I didn't say that the results were wrong or something. I do not want an optimized function for the moment. It was just for comparison purposes; you don't have to give me a lecture on the topic. and then what does your super gsk3 stand for? apparently no sense of humor for you. but anyway... thanks for nothing ;) rest in peace my son

Comment: This is getting some down votes and some close requests. I think to keep it alive you need to do a spot of work on it. I'd suggest you point us to the source of the algorithm you are using, and also tell us how much of it you think is right so far - you say the results seem random points, but are the A's and B's and so on what you expect?

Comment: @Spacedman the algorithm used is a normal cubic spline implementation that uses the tridiagonal matrix algorithm to retrieve the polynomial coefficients for the spline. Down until the #control points the algorithm is correct. The computed coefficients  arrays (e.g., A,B,C,D) seem to be also correct. The problem is that I do not really know how to implement specific control points for the spline, thus not being able to plot the results.

Comment: I'm curious what "not happy about the results" means: would you be interested in expanding?

Comment: @Jesus Christ: "I did not find any specification of the algorithm that is used" - To see the source of the functions, try `stats:::smooth.spline` and `pspline:::smooth.Pspline`. By the way, if you are posting on SO, does this mean that the end times are upon us? Or is it simply that heaven now has the internets? What kind of bandwidth do you get? Fios? Better than fios? I appreciate the heads-up.

Comment: @jthetzel Hehehe... no worries my son! SO will be safe and sound. Is just a try to be cool once again... see the use of these so called computers of yours.. pretty distracting though to see the keyboard buttons through the middle of the hand : / but anything for the internets. BTW thank you for the hint with the source code for the functions. I'll tell my dad about you. What fiber dude... speed light is so 5 minutes ago :]

Answer (score 9):

Okay here goes...

Your 'control points' here are the points at which you are going to evaluate the cubic spline. So the number of points returned (yy) is the same length as xx. This made me spot something:

```
for (j in 1:length(xx)){
  for (i in 1:n){
    if (xx[j]<=x[i]){
      break
    }
    yy[i] = A[i]*(xx[j] - x[i])^3 + B[i]*(xx[j] - x[i])^2 + C[i]*(xx[j] - x[i]) + D[i]

 }
```

This is only computing 'n' values of yy. Hullo, whats wrong here? It should be returning length(xx) values...

Then I think I spotted something else - your 'break' is going to drop out of the for loop. What you really want is to skip that i and go on to the next one until you hit the one relevant to your point:

```
#spline evaluation
for (j in 1:length(xx)){
  for (i in 1:n){
    if (xx[j]<=x[i]){
      next
     }
    yy[j] = A[i]*(xx[j] - x[i])^3 + B[i]*(xx[j] - x[i])^2 + C[i]*(xx[j] - x[i]) + D[i]

 }
}
```

This is inefficient because you are computing some yy[j] and dumping them next time round the loop, but no matter, it gets the job done.

Wrap this into a function, so you can play with it easily. My function 'myspline' takes x and y for data to fit, and an xx vector for prediction locations. I can do:

```
> xx=seq(35,48,len=100)
> yy = myspline(x,y,xx)
> plot(xx,yy,type="l")
> points(x,y)
>
```

And I get a nice curve going through the (x,y) points. Except for the first point which it seems to miss and heads off to zero, so I suspect there's still an off-by-one error somewhere. Oh well. 99% done.

Here's the code:

```
myspline <- function(x,y,xx){

n = length(x)

h=0;yy=0
#determine width of intervals
for (i in 1:(n-1)){
   h[i] = (x[i+1] - x[i])
}

A = 0
B = 0
C = 0
D = 0
#determine the matrix influence coefficients for the natural spline
for (i in 2:(n-1)){
  j = i-1
  D[j] = 2*(h[i-1] + h[i])
  A[j] = h[i]
  B[j] = h[i-1] 

}

#determine the constant matrix C
for (i in 2:(n-1)){
  j = i-1
  C[j] = 6*((y[i+1] - y[i]) / h[i] - (y[i] - y[i-1]) / h[i-1])
}

#maximum TDMA length
ntdma = n - 2

#tridiagonal matrix algorithm

#upper triangularization
R = 0
for (i in 2:ntdma){
  R = B[i]/D[i-1]
  D[i] = D[i] - R * A[i-1]
  C[i] = C[i] - R * C[i-1] 
}

#set the last C
C[ntdma] = C[ntdma] / D[ntdma]

#back substitute
for (i in (ntdma-1):1){
  C[i] = (C[i] - A[i] * C[i+1]) / D[i]
}

#end of tdma

#switch from C to S
S = 0
for (i in 2:(n-1)){
  j = i - 1
  S[i] = C[j]
}
#end conditions
S[1] <- 0 -> S[n]

#Calculate cubic ai,bi,ci and di from S and h
for (i in 1:(n-1)){
 A[i] = (S[i+ 1] - S[i]) / (6 * h[i])
 B[i] = S[i] / 2
 C[i] = (y[i+1] - y[i]) / h[i] - (2 * h[i] * S[i] + h[i] * S[i + 1]) / 6
 D[i] = y[i]
}


#control points
#xx = seq(x[2],x[4],len=100)

#spline evaluation
for (j in 1:length(xx)){
  for (i in 1:n){
    if (xx[j]<=x[i]){
      next
     }
    yy[j] = A[i]*(xx[j] - x[i])^3 + B[i]*(xx[j] - x[i])^2 + C[i]*(xx[j] - x[i]) + D[i]
 }
}
return(yy)
}
```

Comment: +1 For beatification-worthy effort.

Comment: It's the only way I'll attain sainthood. Or 10k rep...

Comment: @Spacedman Thank you. You are right, the spline is a bit shifted, but I will manage to correct it. ..probably a loop somewhere. And after I will get it into a more R specific "shape". Thank you once again for your help. Not like the others so called experts that are just good at flapping their fingers and criticize without helping any. Well I'm off... daddamn it's hard to walk straight with all this f**ed up blood of mine. Thank you man. See you later ;]

Comment: hehe. there's a lot of things in there that can be optimised by doing vectors all in one go and not having loops, but some of your code wont admit to that because its a bit recursive - x[i+1] depending on x[i] and so on. If you want help on that process, create some simple, isolated, reproducible (cut n paste) examples as new questions and I'm sure the guys will have a go!

Comment: well the optimization was not the point here. The thing is that I applied already 3 different smoothing techniques (2 built in and one implemented) on the data and I wanted to have a fourth one to see how much data I am losing if the data points are close enough or scattered. I still have to apply a smoothing parameter on the second derivative, but again it was just for comparison purposes. It is pretty much sensitive data that I deal with and I will also pass it through the Matlab smoothing functions. I am a noob in R as I just started using it 3 weeks ago, so..yeah.. optimization is far away